# Parsing URL query in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, url

Assuming a URL of `www.domain.org?x=1&y=2&z=3`, what would be a smart method to separate out the query elements of a URL in PHP without using GET or REQUEST?

```
  $url = parse_url($url);
  echo $url[fragment];
```

I don't think it's possible to return query parts separately, is it?  From what I can tell, the query will just say `x=1&y=2&z=3`, but please let me know if I am wrong. Otherwise, what would you do to parse the `$url[query]`?

---

Fragment should be Query instead. Sorry for the confusion; I am learning!

Comment: FYI: `$url[fragment]` means "get the value of the constant `fragment` and use this to get the key from `$url`". You probably means `$url['fragment']`? Fragments are stuff after `#` btw. If you're looking for the variables between `?` and `#` this is the "query".

Comment: Are you simply looking for `$_GET['x']` or are you parsing a URL separate from the one belonging to your script?

Comment: Ok, so after the `?` in the url is called the argument.  Got that now.  I already understood `$_GET[]` but my thought is about processing the `$url` and not using that function.

Comment: `query` or `Query`?

Answer (score 10):

You can take the second step and parse the query string using [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$url = 'www.domain.org?x=1&y=2&z=3';
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url_parts['query'], $query_parts);
var_dump($query_parts);
```

I assumed you meant the query string instead of the fragment because there isn't a standard pattern for fragments.

Answer (score 3):

The [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function returns several components, including `query`. To parse it you should run [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsedUrl['query'], $parsedQueryString);
```

If you are going just to parse your HTTP request URL:

- use the `$_REQUEST['x']`, `$_REQUEST['y']`, and `$_REQUEST['z']` variables to access the *x*, *y*, and *z* parameters;
- use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the whole URL query string.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting errors with some of the answers, but they did lead me to the right answer.

```
 $url = 'www.domain.org?x=1&y=2&z=3';
 $query = $url[query]; 
 parse_str($query);
 echo "$x &y $z";
```

And this outputs `1 2 3`, which is what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner with no error checking

```
parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);
```

`$query` will contain the query string parameters. 
Unlike PHP's `$_GET`, this will work with query parameters of any length.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [this URL wrapper](https://github.com/weew/url) (which I have written).

It is capable of parsing URLs of complexity like `protocol://username:password@subdomain.domain.tld:80/some/path?query=value#fragment` and has many more *goodies*.