# how to get last id number from url using php

Tags: php

i want get last id from url, 
i have url from text file like this

```
http://domain.com/..../pid=87dhdhjkh&tid=87ehjdhnjh
```

how to get output `87ehjdhnjh`

i have this code

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
$line = fgets($file);
# do same stuff with the $line


$str = ($line);


if(preg_replace("/.+?\.*/", "$str", $m)){
echo  $m[1] .'<br>' ;
}
```

but not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing URL query in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750367/parsing-url-query-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$input_value = 'http://domain.com/..../pid=87dhdhjkh&tid=87ehjdhnjh';
$last = explode('=', strstr($input_value, '&tid'));
echo $last[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to just parse your url.

Let's say you have variable callde `$url` storing your url as a string, if you just use parse_url() function here is what you get:

```
$url = "http://domain.com/.../pid=87dhdhjkh&tid=87ehjdhnjh";

$result = parse_url($url);
```

You will get this as an output:

```
Array (
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => domain.com
    [path] => /.../pid=87dhdhjkh&tid=87ehjdhnjh 
)
```

After that you can get `path` from that array and parse it using parse_str() function:

```
parse_str($result['path'], $output);

print_r($output);
```

The output will be following:

```
Array
(
    [/___/pid] => 87dhdhjkh
    [tid] => 87ehjdhnjh
)
```

Now that array is stored in $output and you can retrieve value of `tid` from it, which is what you needed:

`print $output['tid'];`

So to summarize here is everything you need:

```
$url = "http://domain.com/.../pid=87dhdhjkh&tid=87ehjdhnjh";

$result = parse_url($url);
parse_str($result['path'], $output);
print $output['tid'];
```

UPDATE:

This question and answer might be considered as duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480852/2267244

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function

```
$line = 'http://domain.com/.../pid=87dhdhjkh&tid=87ehjdhnjh';
$pattern = '/\&tid\=([^\&]+)/';

preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if(count($matches) > 0) {
    echo $matches[1][0];
}
```